# How do I add HTTP headers when making calls to the Google Drive service via the Google API Python Client?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm building an app that fetches documents from Google Drive via the Drive API. I'd like to add an 'Accept Encoding' header to my request. How is this done in Python? I'm using the `google-api-python-client`
I used the code here: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-python as a base for my app, but it doesn't detail how to add custom headers.

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to set accept encoding? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JayLee I'm trying to implement the performance optimization tips suggested here: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/performance

Comment: This is already done for you: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/performance#gzip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need to edit accept encoding since the python client library [accepts and decodes gzip for you.](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/performance#gzip)